# Can I automatically restart a pc with a prompt to restart or postpone

Tags: script

What can I do so that I can have a pc restart at a particular time each night and it prompts the user to continue to restart or postpone with a specific time frame?

Comment: have you tried to accomplish it through **task scheduler** (`taskschd.msc`) ?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try to restart your machine automatically. All you have to do is few steps,

1. In control panel, under Administrative Tools, click on Scheduled Tasks
   Once Task Scheduler is opened up, choose Create Basic Tasks on the right side of the window.
2. Under Name you can choose any desired name for the task, say for ex: Autorestart and press Next
3. In the Trigger tab, you can choose your desired time frame and press Next.
4. Specify the time to restart the machine and press Next.
5. In the Action tab choose Start a Program and press Next.
6. In the Program/Script field, browse the system32 folder (by default C:\Windows\System32) and choose the program shutdown.exe and press open. Type -F -R in the Add arguments(optional) field and press Next.
7. Once done click Next.